# How to hide scrollbar in a div

Tags: html, css

I have made a div which wraps the overflow content scrollable but I want it's scroll to be hidden but div remains scroll-able.

```
.description
{
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

<div class="description">
    <h4>Description</h4>
    <p>After a series of deadly discoveries, Bruce Wayne has learned that the Court of Owls is real � and a deadly threat out to control Gotham City! Unleashing their deadly assassins known as the Talons, Batman must stop the insidious Court of Owls before they claim the city for their own. In doing so, The Dark Knight will uncover dark secrets � not just about the city he�s sworn to protect, but about the history of the Wayne family.After a series of deadly discoveries, Bruce Wayne has learned that the Court of Owls is real � and a deadly threat out to control Gotham City! Unleashing their deadly assassins known as the Talons, Batman must stop the insidious Court of Owls before they claim the city for their own. In doing so, The Dark Knight will uncover dark secrets � not just about the city he�s sworn to protect, but about the history of the Wayne family.After a series of deadly discoveries, Bruce Wayne has learned that the Court of Owls is real � and a deadly threat out to control Gotham City! Unleashing their deadly assassins known as the Talons, Batman must stop the insidious Court of Owls before they claim the city for their own. In doing so, The Dark Knight will uncover dark secrets � not just about the city he�s sworn to protect, but about the history of the Wayne family.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1438/, i tested it on mozilla

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make your scroll bar hidden by applying **3 lines** of **CSS** that will work in all different browsers. Try below **CSS**. **[UPDATE]**

**CSS :**

```css
.classname {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* for Internet Explorer, Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* for Firefox */
}

.classname::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  /* for Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xet3r59k/3/

Comment: can you tell me that the same will work fine in other browsers like MOZILLA or IE?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kurlak/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari/)?

Comment: this will not work on any other browser except for chrome